# What do the alternatives for the dialog "Delete Unmapped Tables and Views" do?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have an entity framework model connected to an SQL Server database. I want to remove a table from the model but not from the database. So I press delete on the table in the model and get a dialog:

```
Delete Unmapped Tables and Views

The following tables and views in the store model will no longer be mapped. Do you want them deleted?

Yes No Cancel
```

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd673936%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Yes: In addition to the objects in the conceptual model that you selected for deletion, all unmapped objects (shown in the dialog box display) are deleted from the storage model. This includes objects in the storage model that were already unmapped, not just objects that have become unmapped as a result of the deleting the selected conceptual model objects.

No: No objects will be deleted from the storage model. Only the objects in the conceptual model that you selected will be deleted.

Cancel: The operation is canceled. No objects in the conceptual model or storage model will be deleted.
```

**So if I understand this correctly, yes and no will both delete the table from the model whereas cancel will not?**

**Is no also a safe button to press in that it will not drop the table from the database or delete its data?**

I am running visual studio 2012, C#, .NET 4.5, and SQL Server 2012

Comment: Ugh, designer tools are awful this way, no? Have you considered EFCF instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what they really mean:

Yes - delete from the designer and from the sql database.

No - delete from designer

Cancel - does not delete anything

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is half correct.  Yes does NOT delete the underlying sql table.

[image]

- No - Deletes from the Diagram but not the .Store storage model:

[image]

- Yes - Deletes from both the Diagram AND the .Store storage model.  NOT the actual Db table.
- I do this often when making drastic changes to table structures, i.e. changing column names etc.  Choose Yes, then Update Model from DB, and re-add the table.